# How to determine if object is array-like and convert it into array?

Tags: javascript

I'm using [dep-object-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff#updateddiff), which returns differences between two objects.

The problem is that if I have something like,

```
const objectA = {
  fieldA: 5,
  fieldB: ['123']
}
const objectB = {
  fieldA: 5,
  fieldB: ['123', '456']
}
```

Then it returns,

```
const diff = {
  fieldB: {
    0: '456'
  }
}
```

When the required response object should be,

```
const diff = {
  fieldB: ['456']
}
```

How can I detect if `diff.fieldB` is an array (dynamically, without hardcoding), and consequently convert it into one?

---

## Edit

Thanks to @Nina Scholz, I ended up using her approach as the base. The problem which I caught with my data, however, was that the approach didn't work for strings. Anyway, I ended up implementing it as follows:

```js
const diffs = {
  fieldA: "SOME_STRING",
  fieldB: {
    3: '123',
    5: '456'
  },
};

const chronologize = (object) => {
  let counter = 0;

  for (let prop in object) {
    if (object[prop]) {
      object[counter] = object[prop];
      delete object[prop];
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return object;
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(diffs).map(([k, v]) =>
    typeof v === 'string'
      ? [k, v]
      : [k, Object.assign([], chronologize(v))]),
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what should happen, if you have no array like object?

Comment: Well, the object may contain properties the have values that are arrays or strings. Your answer worked brilliantly for the use case I posted, but sometimes the diff object can be `const diff = { fieldA: 10, fieldB: { 3: '456' } }`, where `fieldB.length === 4`. This means that `fieldA` changed and that `fieldB` also changed -- the change in `fieldB` being an addition of an element to the array. I worked around this, however, using your approach as a base. I had to do several more transformations, such as making sure it's `{ 0: '456' }` and not `{ 3: '456' }`, but that's ok, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the entries, convert the array like object to array with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and an array as target and convert back to an object.

```js
const 
    diff = { fieldB: { 0: '456' } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(diff).map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.assign([], v)]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello, sorry, I know this wasn't asked, but what if it's `const diff = { fieldA: 'someString', fieldB: { 0: '456' } }`?

Comment: the result is funny, you get single letters for a string value. `{
  "fieldA": [
    "s",
    "o",
    "m",
    "e",
    "S",
    "t",
    "r",
    "i",
    "n",
    "g"
  ],
  "fieldB": [
    "456"
  ]
}`